# Install latest version of mono-complete on docker

Tags: python, .net, docker, mono, python.net

```
RUN apt-get update 
    apt-get install -y mono-complete
```

I have added this on the docker file, but I get this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clr_loader/mono.py:180: UserWarning: Hosting Mono versions before v6.12 is known to be problematic. If the process crashes shortly after you see this message, try updating Mono to at least v6.12.
```

I tried mentioning the versions like below:

```
apt-get install -y mono-complete@6.12.0
```

But it says it could not find that version.

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning you should read, understand and remember.

Comment: `mono.py` is not even part of Mono.